# Send notification for specific group in odoo

Tags: python, odoo

I want to send notificaton for everyone in manfacture group so i tried this code but it does not work

```
manf_categ_ids=self.pool.get('ir.module.category').search(cr,uid,[('name','=','Manufacturing')],context=context)[0]
    users=self.pool.get('res.groups').browse(cr, uid, manf_categ_ids , context=context).users
    for user in users:
        recipient_partners = []
        recipient_partners.append(
            (4, user.partner_id.id)
        )       
    #user_ids=self.pool.get('res.users').search(cr,uid,[('groups_id','=',manf_categ_ids)],context=context)
    post_vars = {'subject': "notification about order",
         'body': "Yes inform me as i belong to manfacture group",
         'partner_ids': recipient_partners,} # Where "4" adds the ID to the list 
                                   # of followers and "3" is the partner ID 
    thread_pool = self.pool.get('mail.thread')
    thread_pool.message_post(
            cr, uid, False,
            type="notification",
            subtype="mt_comment",
            context=context,
            **post_vars)
```

the problem that 2 users belongs to manufacture group ,but the list of users is only contain 1 element and this code does not send any notification when i log in with this user

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all you need to use **partner's** id, not **user's** id. Second of all you need to add all users, not only the first one.

This is a code based on what I use in my project to create an array that can be used as a value for the `partner_ids` argument:

```
group = self.env['res.groups'].search([('category_id.name', '=', 'Manufacturing')])
recipient_partners = []
for recipient in group.users: 
    recipient_partners.append(
        (4, recipient.partner_id.id)
    )
```

You can see [the code this is based on here](https://github.com/EE/bestja/blob/master/addons/message_template/models.py). It starts with the MessageTemplate's `send_group` method and continues into the `send` method.

You don't seem to currently use the new Odoo ORM API. You can either start using it (I highly recommend it!) or add the arguments required by the old API (cr, uid, context) to the `search()` method and use `browse()` to get full user objects.

Comment: Thanks for your replay but i modified my code to look like your (without using new odoo api)but still this code send only notification for admin but the other users who belongs to manufacture group don't get any notification on their messages i dont know why ??do u have any idea why only the users contain the admin only

Comment: Try making sure the `users` list actually contain the users you want.

Comment: This my question why users list contains only admin and the other users who are user or manager in manufacture group dont appears in this list

Comment: I don't understand why you get an id of a category and try to obtain a group of that id. Those are completely different models, with different ids.

Comment: as i don't know the group name of manufacture  so im try to get category and then try group of that category

Comment: @LudwikTrammer I've been strangling with the same task, i managed to do it but there's an issue. When i send the notification to someone who's not online, when he come's online the message doesn't appear.
Can you help me with this please;

Comment: you don't need the loop, just do "group.users.partner_id.ids" to get list

Answer (score 6):

The problem seems to be that you clear the list each iteration.

The line

```
recipient_partners = []
```

should be out of the `for` loop.